# Por que se escreve 1Pedro e não 1 Pedro

Tags: ortografia

Eu encontrei em muitos livros a convenção de escrever o nome de alguns livros da Bíblia sem um espaço entre o número e o resto do título.

**Exemplos:**

Por exemplo, o Rev. Hernandes Dias Lopes escreveu *1Coríntios* ao invés de *1 Coríntios* (com espaço) no seu livro *Pregação Expositivo* (pg. 115):

> O apóstolo Paulo resume a sua teologia da pregação em 1Coríntios 1-4,
> apontando para a supremacia  de Jesus Cristo.

Semelhantemente, o Dr. Augustus Nicodemus Lopes escreveu o seguinte no seu livro *Uma Igreja Complicada* (pg. 27):

> A pergunta é se essa oposição já existia ao tempo de 1Coríntios.

Eu tenho mais um exemplo. No seu livro *O Credo dos Apóstolos*, Franklin Ferreira escreveu (pg. 62):

> No entanto, somos surpreendidos ao ler Atos, 1Timóteo, 2Timóteo e Tito
> e descobrir que a igreja não se reunia em edifícios próprios.

**Observação:**

Então, entre vários autores e vários editores, todos estão seguindo a mesma norma. Parece que não tem diversidade acerca desta prática.

**Para clarificar:**

Minha pergunta *não* trata de estilo, pontuação, abreviações ou como escrever referências.

Ela trata da ortografia de exatamente 17 nomes:

> 1Samuel, 2Samuel, 1Reis, 2Reis, 1Crônicas, 2Crônicas, 1Coríntios,
> 2Coríntios, 1Tessalonicenses, 2Tessalonicenses, 1Timóteo, 2Timóteo,
> 1Pedro, 2Pedro, 1João, 2João, 3João

**Eis minha pergunta:** Por que se escrevem os nomes dos livros assim? Como foi decidido que se deve fazer isto deste jeito?

Na minha opinião, seria mais natural escrevê-los assim:

> 1 Samuel, 2 Samuel, 1 Reis, 2 Reis, 1 Crônicas, 2 Crônicas, 1
> Coríntios, 2 Coríntios, 1 Tessalonicenses, 2 Tessalonicenses, 1
> Timóteo, 2 Timóteo, 1 Pedro, 2 Pedro, 1 João, 2 João, 3 João

Comment: Livro 1 Coríntios 13, O 1 antes do nome do livro se refere ao Livro, os números depois aos versículos.

Comment: @Lambie. Eu sei. A pergunta trata da falta de espaço entre o número e resto do título: 1Pedro ao invés de 1 Pedro.

Comment: Tá OK. Não tinha entendido.

Comment: Sid, na minha opinião a tradição manda escrever com espaço: por exemplo, os livros do sXIX no Google Books têm todos espaço. A lógica também: afinal são duas palavras, ainda que uma representada por um algarismo. Onde é correto escrever pegado é em abreviações (2Cor 3:5, por exemplo). Há de facto muitos livros com tudo pegado. São todos relativamente recentes, e creio que se deve a falta de atenção à tradição gráfica.

Comment: @Jacinto. Eu concordo. Obrigado pelo comentário.

Comment: @Sid, desculpa pela chatice, mas acho que o correto é "[...]Por que se escrevem os nomes[...]. Desculpa se eu estiver errado.

Comment: @Schilive. Eu concertei isto. Obrigado!

Comment: @Sid, disponha.

Answer (score -1):

Há vários formatos para escrever referências a livros, capítulos e versículos da bíblia.

Pode ver na wikipedia [alguns dos vários guias de estilo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bible_citation) e convenções.

Por exemplo, na rede Stack Exchange é recomendado seguir o *[Chicago Manual of Style](https://www.chicagomanualofstyle.org/search.html?clause=bible)*, que inclui normas para escrever as ditas referências.

No exemplo da pergunta, o *Chicago Manual of Style* recomenda escrever os nomes completos dos livros nos textos, e só escrever a forma abreviada em rodapés e citações.

> - [**Chicago Style -- General Guidelines**](https://hbl.gcc.libguides.com/c.php?g=339562&p=2286666)
> - Do not abbreviate books of the Bible in the text of your paper.
>
>   Example:  2 Samuel 12 records the prophet Nathan’s confrontation of King David.

Exemplo de usos recomendados das abreviações:

> - [**Footnotes/Endnotes/Parenthetical References**](https://hbl.gcc.libguides.com/c.php?g=339562&p=2286666)
> - (...) You do not need to include the Bible in your bibliography.
> - When you are citing a particular passage of Scripture, include the abbreviated name of the book, the chapter number, and the verse number—never a page number. Chapter and verse are separated by a colon.
>
>   Example:  1 Cor. 13:4, 15:12-19

**EDIT**:

Nos comentários foi pedido para especificar a norma aplicada no Brasil tendo o formato das referências com número e nome do livro sem espaço no meio.

Penso que a entidade de referência será a [*ABNT - Associação Brasileira de Normas Técnicas*](https://www.abntcatalogo.com.br). Os artigos desta entidade são pagos.

No entanto, encontrei outro documento o: [*"Manual para apresentação de trabalhos académicos da PUC-SP"*](https://www.pucsp.br/sites/default/files/parte-da-mensagem-anexada.pdf). Na introdução diz seguir os critérios da ABNT com exemplos.

Olhando para os exemplos na página 105 pôde ler-se que a ABNT não especifica um modelo para as referências. No entanto nas páginas anteriores, são incluídas tabelas que seguem um modelo igual ao da pergunta, veja o Quadro 7 da página 103.

> - **11 MODELOS DE REFERÊNCIAS DA BÍBLIA**
>   Na referência de um trabalho, é preciso indicar a versão da Bíblia utilizada. A norma da  Associação  Brasileira  de  Normas  Técnicas  (ABNT),  para  elaboração  de  referências bibliográficas – ABNT NBR 6023:2018, não especifica um modelo para referenciar a Bíblia.

> Por que se escreve os nomes dos livros assim? Como foi decidido que se deve fazer isto deste jeito?

Se for à página 107 vai ver uma lista de referências para os capítulos sobre as normas aplicadas ao textos bíblicos. Vai reparar que para além da ABNT são includías normas usadas por algumas editoras específicas. É questão de a editora de um livro adpotar uma norma e segui-la, os exemplos que deu na pergunta resultam de as editoras para esses livros terem seguido normas diferentes.

- (Aqui é de referir que a pergunta inicial entrou em contradição. A pergunta começou por dar dois exemplos que seguiam normas diferentes - perguntando sobre a diferença. Depois foi editada para concluir que não há diferença e perguntando sobre a semelhança. Penso que, em ambos os casos, a resposta dada é completa e exaustiva.)

**Actualização**:

> Então, entre vários autores e vários editores, todos estão seguindo a mesma norma. Parece que não tem diversidade acerca desta prática.

Um contra-exemplo a esta afirmação, para ilustrar o que os guias de estilo citados indicam, pode ser visto numa edição geralmente considerada de referência pelo seu valor histórico. Se virmos a *King James Version (KJV)* os titulos e cabeçalhos seguem um estilo, enquanto os rodapés seguem outro. Bem visível em [`1 Jhon 4`](https://www.kingjamesbibleonline.org/1-John-Chapter-4/) que usa o espaço mas na mesma página no rodapé indica a referência sem espaço `2Ti 2:12`.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, mas não estou persuadido que tem muitos brasileiros que observam (ou acham que devem observar) o Chicago Manual of Style.

Comment: @Sid editei a pergunta.

Comment: The Chicago Manual of Style is completely irrelevant here. Why are you citing English stuff?

Comment: Todos os exemplo seguiram a mesma norma: a falta de espaço. Mais exemplos: 1João, 2João, 3João, 1Pedro, 2Pedro, 1Coríntios, 2Coríntios 1Samuel, 2Samuel....

Comment: Por que está falando sobre a King James Version? Em inglês, se escreve com espaço (ex. 1 John), mas minha pergunta trata da ortografia portuguesa.

Comment: @Sid tu não viste guias de estilo em português, ingluês e normas internacionas incluidos na resposta?? Vê lá bem.

Comment: Dei uma olhada, mas não tinha nada que trata desta pergunta.

Comment: @Sid então é melhor veres outra vez porque está aí tudo explicado e esclarecido.

Comment: Não acho nada. Se tiver alguma coisa, pode incluir na sua resposta.

Comment: A única coisa que chega perto é a frase: "Quando se faz referência a um livro ou capítulo no corpo do texto, deve ser digitado o nome completo do livro." Bem. Isto não tem nada a dizer acerca da ortografia do nome. Portanto não responde a minha pergunta.

Comment: @Sid, posso estar errado, mas acredito que o respondedor tenha quisto dizer que basicamente depende do estilo, não havendo um mais correto que o outro. Também creio que ele/ela tenha incluído referências à língua inglesa para mostrar que a situação da língua inglesa, em relação a isso, é a mesma da portuguesa: é uma questão de estilo, não de certo ou errado. Não é a minha opinião desse âmbito, é a minha interpretação deste texto respondente, que não é infalível.

Comment: @Sid, desculpa, mas acho que não e sobre ortografia. Até onde eu sei, que é pouco, ortografia é o sistema de como se escrevem palavras -- não sei se pontuação se inclui. Acho que a resposta é sobre estilo, porque não existe uma regra, mas sim convenções, sobre isso. Por exemplo, "referência: Priberam 'idéia'" e "informação extraída do Priberam 'déia'", que expressam a mesma coisa, mas de formas diferentes. Pelo que eu vi da tua pergunta, bad_coder a responde indiretamente, se a minha interpretação estava correta. Se ele não te respondeu a pergunta, como ela poderia ser respondida?

Comment: @Schilive. Minha pergunta é sobre como se escreve palavras. Não trata de pontuação, nem referências. É só ortografia. Então esta resposta fala sobre muito que não tem nada a ver com a pergunta.

Comment: @Sid, então recomendo mudar a tua pergunta, porque duas pessoas já tiveram interpretações erradas, eu e o bad_coder, e a nossa interpretação até deve ter sido parecida. Eu não estava falando de referências naquele comentário. Desculpa pela chatice, mas o correto é "como se escrevem palavras", não "como se escreve palavras"; desculpa pela chatice.

Comment: @Schilive. OK. Eu atualizei a pergunta.